# Can I set application pool in webconfig?

Tags: .net, web-applications, iis-7, application-pool

I use IIS 7.0 and I want to know how if I can set Appliacation pool in web config file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Choosing the application pool for your application is a "Setup" issue, rather then a "configuration".

Comment: Is there any way to set my application pool in visual stuido before publish my web site?

Comment: @cagin Check out this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658675/how-can-i-create-a-new-application-pool-in-a-web-setup-project

Answer (score -3):

Use `Pooling=False;` in your connection string to disable pooling in your app. If you want to configure it, you can add something like this `Max pool size=200; Min poolsize=0`.

[More info about pooling you can find here...](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/61/posts/11202/connection-pooling-in-adonet.aspx)

Comment: I think cagin was asking about IIS application pools, not SQL Server connection pooling...