# Can we add WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE=1 to web.config

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, x509certificate

I am facing **CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified** error when application is hosted on azure on using certificates? For now all i can see is that we have to add WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE=1 to app settings in azure if we are using azure app services. But how do we achieve it if we are not using app services

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't.

Even if you use IIS 7, your option is to set `Load User Profile` option as `True` in the IIS Application Pool configuration, you could not set it in the web config file. If you use other cloud services, I think there also should be a setting like `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE` in azure.

For more details, you could refer to the links below.

1. [X509Certificate Constructor Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951729/x509certificate-constructor-exception)
2. [What exactly happens when I set LoadUserProfile of IIS pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149132/what-exactly-happens-when-i-set-loaduserprofile-of-iis-pool)
3. [Can I set application pool in webconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635177/can-i-set-application-pool-in-webconfig)

Comment: For me things did't work even after setting `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE` to 1 when my app service plan was using `Free` tier. It started to work after I upgraded it to `S1` tier.