# How to create a web setup allowing the user to create new website and application pool?

Tags: windows-installer, setup-project, custom-action, web-setup-project

I have to create a web setup with the user be able to create a new application pool and new website. I have been able to create new website and new application pool through custom action. For this purpose I have a windows dialog form to take input from the user and create new or use existing application pool and website.

Since I am using windows dialog form, I deleted the installation address dialog from the user interface views of the setup project. The setup creates the application pool and the website but the files are not extracted. So I think the installer does not extract the file since I have deleted the installation address dialog from the user interface views.

Can anybody please help me fix this.

Thanks,

Brijesh Gupta

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658675/how-can-i-create-a-new-application-pool-in-a-web-setup-project

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, setup-projects have been removed in VS2012.  If you switch to another windows-installer based tool such as Windows Installer XML (WiX) or InstallShield Limited Edition (Free)  you can declare IIS metadata without having to write any custom actions.

Comment: according to the features page, the free version of InstallShield doesn't support deployment to IIS to setup websites.

Comment: Sure it does.  Section (3) Configure the target system | Internet Information Services.  It brings up a page where the first option is right-click add website.   It would have this functionality because it's meant to have the same functionality as the tool it replaced.

Comment: Makes sense, the features page I was reading must've been outdated

Comment: FWIW, the only limitations of ISLE that are hard to get around is 1 feature and limited UI authoring.  Through creative use of WiX merge modules I can inject all kinds of capabilities into an ISLE built MSI.