# Setting application pool to a specific iis application using servermanager web setup project

Tags: c#, iis, installation

I'm trying to create an application pool before install and set that application pool for the installed application post install in a visual studio web setup project

Trying to filter out the applications under a site so that the newly created application pool applies only to a specific application with the name "websetup9090" in this case. Tried a few methods to compare the name of the applications but none of them worked

or

If there is any way to run the custom action to create the application pool before it reaches the Installation address UI page it would be even better as there is an option to select the application pool for the user via dropdown

The code below is called via custom action in the web setup project

```
   protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        

        ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();

        bool chkPool = false;
        chkPool = iisManager.ApplicationPools.Any(t => t.Name == "Pool99");

        if (chkPool == false)
        {
            var myPool = iisManager.ApplicationPools.Add("Pool99");
            myPool.ManagedPipelineMode = ManagedPipelineMode.Integrated;
            myPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = ".NET CLR version 4.0.30319";
            myPool.Enable32BitAppOnWin64 = true;
            iisManager.CommitChanges();

        }
    }

    protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
        var sites = iisManager.Sites;
        foreach (Site site in sites)
        {
            if (site.Name == "Default Web Site")
            {
                Site mySite = site;
                mySite.Stop();
                var myPools = iisManager.ApplicationPools;

                foreach (ApplicationPool pool in myPools)
                {

                    if (pool.Name == "Pool99")
                    {
                        ApplicationPool myPool = pool;
                        foreach (var item in mySite.Applications)
                        {
                            if (item.Path.ToLower().IndexOf("websetup9090") > 0)
                            {
                                item.ApplicationPoolName = myPool.Name;
                            }
                            
                        }
                        iisManager.CommitChanges();
                        myPool.Recycle();
                    }
                }
                iisManager.CommitChanges();
                mySite.Start();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Test it on a machine without IIS Express installed first.

Comment: you could refer to the this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658675/how-can-i-create-a-new-application-pool-in-a-web-setup-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue with attaching application pool to the newly created application by moving the code in onAfterInstall to Commit method